# floating point output length in bits

Tags: floating-point

We know that floating point representation supports a larger range of numbers, and the operation is slower, than with pure integers. Also, we know that mantissa and exponents are used to represent a floating point.

In a 32-bit system, s* b^e the output is longer than 32-bit or 32 bit? (where s=significand, b=base,e=exponent)?

Comment: What do you mean by "output" in the phrase "the output is longer than 32-bit or 32 bit"? Do you mean the "actual number of bytes used in the representation"?

Comment: @cirosantilli i mean the value of the expression when evaluated. The representation is itself 32-bit in a 32-bit platform right?

Comment: I don't understand very well what you mean by "the expression when evaluated". Can you post some sample code in at least one arch / language?

Comment: Say,I have to store 2147483648 as a float(not as a fixed-point number like integer) in a 32-bit system. For this what will be the mantissa (significand) and exponent ? @cirosantilli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact number of bits used to represent the mantissa and exponent of floating point numbers varies from CPU to CPU, so the question is certainly architecture dependent.

There is one standard which is very dominant: [IEEE Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), and according to [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234468/do-any-real-world-cpus-not-use-ieee-754) all major CPUs you are likely to meet today implement it, including IA32.

According to Wikipedia, IEEE Floating Point requires that at least one of the following be available on any implementation:

- binary32: 24 bit mantissa (including 1 sign bit) and 8  bit exponent
- binary64: 53 bit mantissa (including 1 sign bit) and 11 bit exponent

Assuming that by 32 bit you mean the [IA 32 family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) (which is only one of the few architectures which uses 32 bits), then the floating point registers [can contain up to 80 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format), meaning that, binary32, binary64 and a non IEC 80 bit format with 15 exponent bits can all be supported. To differentiate between 32 bit and 64 bit instructions most assemblers use size modifiers like `QWORD` or `DWORD`.

Also, besides CPU implementations, languages can also require compliance to IEEE Floating Point. In the C language for example, Annex 7 specifies that if the macro `__STDC_IEC_599__` is defined automatically by the compiler then `float` is guaranteed to be binary32 and `double` binary64. `long double` is not fixed to be IEC, so it could then use 80 bits on an IA32 arch.