# How many floating-point types are there in C?

Tags: c, types, floating-point, decimal

As many programmers know there are several floating-point types in C. So far I know `float`, `double` and `long double` but I'm not quite sure they are all of them, cause I found several definitions like `__DEC32_MAX__`. At first I thought that is another name for `__FLT_MAX__` but when I tried to print it, I realized that it's different (as in below):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    __mingw_printf("flt    value: %e, size: %d\n", __FLT_MAX__, sizeof(__FLT_MAX__));
    __mingw_printf("dbl    value: %e, size: %d\n", __DBL_MAX__, sizeof(__DBL_MAX__));
    __mingw_printf("ldbl   value: %e, size: %d\n", __LDBL_MAX__, sizeof(__LDBL_MAX__));
    __mingw_printf("dec32  value: %e, size: %d\n", __DEC32_MAX__, sizeof(__DEC32_MAX__));
    __mingw_printf("dec64  value: %e, size: %d\n", __DEC64_MAX__, sizeof(__DEC64_MAX__));
    __mingw_printf("dec128 value: %e, size: %d\n", __DEC128_MAX__, sizeof(__DEC128_MAX__));
}

/* output:
flt    value: 3.402823e+038, size: 4
dbl    value: 1.797693e+308, size: 8
ldbl   value: 3.237664e-317, size: 16
dec32  value: 9.944455e-315, size: 4
dec64  value: 9.089022e+269, size: 8
dec128 value: 3.237656e-317, size: 16
*/
```

What are **__DEC__*** s?
Are there any other floating-point types that I don't know?

Comment: Standard C have the three you list: `float`, `double` and `long double`. And on some systems `double` and `long double` might be the same.

Comment: By the way, to print a `long double` value you should use the format specifier `%Le`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. And to print a `size_t` (which is the type of the result of `sizeof`) you should use `%zu`.

Comment: And talking about `printf`, why are you using the non-standard `__mingw_printf` instead of the standard `printf`? Similarly with the non-standard constants like `__FLT_MAX__` instead of the standard `FLT_MAX`? What resources are you using to learn C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some specific uses require small floats like: `float8` and `float16` and `bifloat` It is used mainly in the DSP, AI and graphics applications. Many hardware architectures support at least some of them (for example bifloat AVX-512 BF16, ARM-V8.8, AMD ROCm, CUDA and some more).

There are also big float formats like float128. Example hardware: VSX in PowerPC.

Those floats are not supported directly by the standard C. Some compilers support it as an extension.

Answer (score 6):

There are only [3 real floating-point types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types) in C before C23: `float`, `double` and `long double`, which can use arbitrary base for the significand like decimal or octal although nowadays it's most likely binary. Some older systems use [hexadecimal floating-point types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234616/995714). Each of the real floating types can be combined with the `_Complex` or `_Imaginary` keyword to make complex floating types

[C23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) added [3 more real floating-point types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23): `_Decimal32`, `_Decimal64`, and `_Decimal128`, all are decimal types

Anything else if you see would be *compiler extensions* or *internal compiler things*. Those would be prefixed with `__` because **identifiers beginning with double underscores are reserved for implementations**. `__mingw_printf`, `__DBL_MAX__`, `__DEC64_MAX__`... are all internal to the implementation and you aren't supposed to use them directly. Use `FLT_MAX` instead of `__FLT_MAX__`

In fact before C23 there's a decimal floating extension in GCC

> As an extension, GNU C supports decimal floating types as defined in the N1312 draft of ISO/IEC WDTR24732. Support for decimal floating types in GCC will evolve as the draft technical report changes. Calling conventions for any target might also change. Not all targets support decimal floating types.
>
> The decimal floating types are `_Decimal32`, `_Decimal64`, and `_Decimal128`. They use a radix of ten, unlike the floating types `float`, `double`, and `long double` whose radix is not specified by the C standard but is usually two.
>
> #### [6.14 Decimal Floating Types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html)

Since mingw is a GCC port, it also supports that decimal floating extension. Typically in `float.h` the standard constants would be defined as the implementation-specific constants, for example

```
#define LDBL_MAX   __LDBL_MAX__
#define DEC128_MAX __DEC128_MAX__
```

Comment: Aside, other standard FP types include `complex float`, `complex double`, ...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica true. I mean non-complex types

Answer (score 3):

The decimal types are very special, very interesting, and very much not standard (yet). They use an [internal fraction representation which is based on base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point), not base 2. See in particular [IEEE 754-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008_revision#Decimal_arithmetic).

So all of the important, unfortunate, tiresome arguments about [0.1 not being exactly representable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018), about [0.1 + 0.2 not exactly equaling 0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004), go away, and almost miraculously computer floating point can behave just like the decimal floating point we're all used to! But these types, and the `printf` support they'd require, are not standard, popular, or well known — yet.

In IEEE 754-2008, the two principal decimal types are [`decimal32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format) and [`decimal64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format), which are the decimal counterparts to our familiar binary `float` and `double`.  There is also [`decimal128`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format) analogous to `long double`.

---

Footnote: Strictly speaking, it's not quite correct to say that `decimal32` and the rest are the "decimal counterparts" to our "familiar binary" floating-point types like `float` and `double`.  The new decimal types are, AFAIK, indeed guaranteed to be decimal.  But the traditional types `float`, `double`, and `long double` were *not* guaranteed to be binary.  They *usually* were, on virtually every machine you're ever likely to use, but they could also be decimal, on one of the rare old machines that implemented floating-point natively and only in decimal.  On such a machine, you'd notice that `FLT_RADIX` from `<float.h>` was 10.

Comment: Some old hardware even used `FLT_RADIX == 16`.